# how to to delete all separators after the last string

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, sed

we want to delete all "," separator ONLY after the last string ( any string )

```
  echo "df true , , ," |  sed 's/,,*$//'
  df ,true , ,
```

but syntax delete only one ","

what need to fix in my syntax so all "," after the last string will be deleted ?

expected output:

```
df ,true
```

example1

```
echo "dejd ,dede,dede 73hygys626^%%,J , ,  ,," | sed ......

expected output

dejd ,dede,dede 73hygys626^%%,J
```

example2

```
echo "lfr  r.,r,ff rger.ref done ,,, , "

expected output

lfr  r.,r,ff rger.ref done
```

Comment: Try: `sed 's/,//g`

Comment: But this is probably not what you want. It's not clear to me from your question.

Comment: the given sample has spaces between `,` but code attempted doesn't use spaces... please clarify that

Comment: this syntax deleted all "," in line , what we want is to delete the "," only after the last string

Comment: see my update , hope its help

Comment: still not clear.. what defines last string? and still not clear why attempted code doesn't use space... what all characters should be removed including `,` after whatever defines last string?

Comment: last string could be any string except  ","

Comment: space is not `,`... so why is expected output `df ,true` instead of <code>df ,true , , </code>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sed 's/[ ,]*$//'
```

Doesn't this do what you want?